# Execute a function just after the view loads, iphone

Tags: iphone, rss, navigation, tabbar

I am creating a tabbar application. One of the tabs is for an rss feed, which is a navigation application. but when i click the tab bat button, it is taking a while to load the view of that tab. It is because the application is waiting for the feed to be loaded from the server. Is there any way to load the view before the loading of that feed takes place. As of now, i'm giving the request in the viewDidLoad method. Thats what is creating the problem. To which part shall i move the code so that the view is loaded instantaneously when clicking the tabbar button.

Comment: you should rather focus on making your sockets nonblocking / asynchronous.

So instead you display a "loading indicator" whilst you're fetching the RSS feed. And only display once it's loaded.

Comment: I have 3 tab bars, 2 simple applications and a 3rd, this one. After clicking the 3rd tab, the view is still the previous application until the feed is loaded, this is causing me the problem. And of course i'm trying to make it exactly as you suggested, but it can be done only when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [this great article](http://icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation) on this subject on iCodeBlog, it's a very elegant way of doing this. If you submit your rss feed loading as an `NSOperation`, it will take place nicely in the background without blocking your main thread.

Comment: is there any other method than NSOperation?

Comment: is there any reason why the recommended way of doing this won't work for you?

Comment: the tutorial given there is loading the feed on a button click whereas i need to load that automatically..

Comment: The loading is triggered by a call to loadData - this doesn't have to be from a button, just call it when you want - i.e. in your app delegate just call [self loadData]; ?

Comment: Yes, this can be called anywhere you want, on a button press or automatically, it's up to you. You can do it in your 'loadData', or 'viewDidLoad' function or even in 'viewWillAppear'

Comment: There are other ways than NSOperation, but I found the NSOperation way to be very elegant and simple. You said that part of the problem is that it "takes a while to load the view of that tab". That sounds like what you need is perform the lengthy load operation in a separate thread. I think using the NSOperation method is by far the simplest for you.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performRSS:) withObject:<nil afterDelay:0.3f];
```

or

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(performRSS:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and place RSS feed related code in a separate function named "performRSS".

Answer (score 0):

I also think that the problem is more that you don't use the HTTP request asyncronously (as Apple recommends). See this document. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

It worked for me in my applications.